# asp.net c# crystal report export to PDF memory full

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, crystal-reports

I am building a report using Crystal Reports and VS2010: ASP.NET/C# which is fairly big (6 pages using OLE Objects), so I am not sure if that would be the cause or solution to this problem, but I need to know either how to fix this or an alternative. All other reports that I built using OLE Objects in the same manner still export just fine.

The code I am using is:

```
protected void exportPDF_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReportDocument repDoc = getReportDocument(); //regathers the report

    Response.Buffer = false;

    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();

    try
    {
        repDoc.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, true, "filename");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        ex = null;
    }
    finally
    {
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

The problem is that I keep getting an error that says:

> Memory Full, Failed to export the report, Not enough memory for
>   operation

Other solutions I have tried:

- Resetting IIS
- Restarting Server
- Installing CutePDF as suggested:
  [Crystal Report 2008 - Memory Full](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757623/crystal-report-2008-memory-full)
- Changing 3rd param from true to false resulting in this line of code:

  repDoc.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, false, "filename");
- Using ExportToDisk as opposed to ExportToHttpResponse, resulting in
  this code:

  repDoc.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, @"Z:\KFauver\test\file.pdf");

This report is one of the last items that I need to complete to finally be able to push to beta test. However, I am now officially lost as to how to export this to PDF (or anything for that matter). Any help is appreciated! Whether it be a fix or an alternative, ill try it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are your OLE objects pictures?

Comment: Word docs. I split a big word doc into separate pages. On the last one I did, it worked fine.

Comment: Which service pack of CR are you on? Have you tried exporting to pdf using the viewer?

Comment: I added CR to my VS not too long ago. What do you mean "export using the viewer"? you mean the viewer tab? I need to be able to have a tech in my office access this from the asp.net page and export from there.

Comment: When you open the asp.net page in a browser, the report gets rendered in a Crystal Reports Viewer. That viewer has an export button among other buttons. Can you export the report using the viewer's button?

Comment: Ahhh that viewer. Last time I tried using that button I got a god awful amount of errors. So I decided to make my own button. Ill give the viewer button another try and post back.

Comment: That'll sort of determine whether YOUR button is faulty or there is something wrong with CR.

Comment: The export button does not work from the viewer. I still get "memory full" error. When I used it on another report that works, I get "Database Logon Failed" because I am doing all that manually.

Comment: So that tells us that possibly something with the CR runtime is not correct. One more test I would do before pursuing the runtime is to remove the OLE objects from the report and see if that is the cause for the error. Other than that update your CR runtime to the latest version.

Comment: I dont think its the OLE objects themselves because I have another report that holds three OLE objects, and exports just fine. Im going to try to create printscreens and put the images on the report instead of OLE objects, see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, having 6 instances of a word doc OLE object on a report will cause it to need too much memory. I did not realize this. My fix was to take screenshots of every page and paste the images into the report. Seems to work just fine that way.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem near two weeks ago and my project due to this error was pending. After trying any action like  below .
Install few PDF printer 
Update my Crystal report version
Change the default Printer and …

At the end my problem has been solved by checked of No printer(optimize for screen display) in crystal report and save the report.
Now it works good
Thanks